# Pyinstaller having issues with import of librairies

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was working with python (which I rarely do) for a simple program that macros some functionalities with certain keyboard inputs. I decided to export the script to a .exe using pyinstaller so I go ahead and run command: `pyinstaller --onefile code.py` and it generates the code.exe as expected. Only for my .exe to crash instantly. I got a view of the error by running it with cmd and got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module  
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module  
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>  
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend  
ImportError  
[1284] Failed to execute script 'code' due to unhandled exception!
```

I'm certain there is an explanation to this so here are my imports:

```
from pynput import keyboard   
from pynput.keyboard import Key   
from pywinauto import application   
from pywinauto.findwindows 
import WindowAmbiguousError, WindowNotFoundError   
import os
```

I couldn't seem to find any similar problems on here. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your .spec file, you should add all of your modules as "hidden imports", this usually fixes all module not found errors.

`hiddenimport=["pynput","pywinauto"]`

Then run pyinstaller with the spec file

`pyinstaller my.spec`

I'd also ensure you're using a virtual environment during this entire process.